# i want to show or hide some controls in repeater through javascript in c# 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control in which i have loaded questions. I want to display a textbox and a button when some one click the question and answer that question with out posting back the page. the textbox and button get hide when the user post the answer

Comment: yeah, so? what's your issue - what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

U could do this with ajax using an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28VS.90%29.aspx).
The javascript will be generated for you by the ASP.NET engine.

You can learn more on the UpdatePanel [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: What did you try??? No one will be able to help you if you want tell **what** is the problem.
Genarally, what you have to do is, wrap each repeater-element's items in one UpdatePanel, and disable the button when clicked (via code-behind).

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <span onclick="ShowTextBox(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>)"><%# Eval("Question") %> </span>
            <div style="display:none" id='<%# "dv_"+Container.ItemIndex %>'>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

AND Add some script

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowTextBox(index) {
            $("#dv_" + index).show();

        }
    </script>`
```

Remember you should include the jquery file in the head.
download from jquery.com